# Sum of Gridview columns/rows ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to make sums of columns and rows in a gridview , I tried so many ways and I can't do it. I'm trying to understand what's wrong. I'm sorry If my code is a mess. I'm using ASP.NET C#. For now it is enough to show sum only in a response.write, later i'll put it on a column/row.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=***;User=***;password=**");

        //query para o select das especialidades todas
        string specstring = "SELECT Speciality.Shortname, SUM(1) as contar " +
                            "FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails INNER JOIN " +
                            "Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN " +
                            " GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId " +
                            " WHERE (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48) " +
                            " GROUP BY Speciality.Shortname ";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(specstring, conn);
        command.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataTable specstringtable = new DataTable();

        myDataAdapter.Fill(specstringtable);
        specstring = ""; 

        for (int i = 0; i < specstringtable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            if (specstring == "")
            {

                specstring = "[" + specstringtable.Rows[i][0] + "]".ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                specstring = specstring + ", " + "[" + specstringtable.Rows[i][0] + "]";

            }

        }


        command.Connection.Close();

        ////query para a pivot table
        string querystring = "SELECT Description AS Categoria, " + specstring +
                             "FROM (SELECT GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname, SUM(1) AS contar, GroupType.GroupId " +
                             "FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails INNER JOIN " +
                             "Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN " +
                             "GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId " +
                             "WHERE (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48) " +
                             "GROUP BY GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname, DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId, GroupType.GroupId) as ps " +
                             "PIVOT (SUM(contar) FOR Shortname IN (" + specstring + ")) pvt " +
                             "ORDER BY GroupId; ";

        ////Response.Write(querystring);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(querystring, conn);
        command2.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter2.SelectCommand = command2;


        DataTable cobtable = new DataTable();

        myDataAdapter2.Fill(cobtable);


        DataColumn cl = cobtable.Columns.Add("Total");
        cobtable.Columns["Total"].SetOrdinal(1);

        DataRow dr;
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "Total";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 1);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "%";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 3);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 4);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "%";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 6);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 7);
        dr = cobtable.NewRow();
        dr["Categoria"] = "%";
        cobtable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 9);

        GroupGrid.DataSource = cobtable;
        GroupGrid.DataBind();

       //GroupGrid.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = cobtable.Compute("sum(" + cobtable.Columns[3].ColumnName + ")", null).ToString();

        decimal a = 0, soma = 0;
        string la = "";
        //Response.Write(GroupGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Count);

        for (int i = 3; i <= (GroupGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Count); i++)
        {
            Response.Write("!");
            //string l3 = GroupGrid.Rows[6].Cells[i-1].Text;
            // Response.Write(l3);
            Response.Write(GroupGrid.Rows[5].Cells[i - 1].Text);
            // la = GroupGrid.Rows[5].Cells[i - 1].Text;
            // sum += Convert.ToInt32(la);
            //sum =  Convert.ToInt32(GroupGrid.Rows[5].Cells[i - 1].Text.ToString());
            //a = a + sum;
            //GroupGrid.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = sum.ToString();
        }

       // Response.Write(a.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right your code is a little mess ;)

I tried to understand what you mean so just for a case here you have the example how to sum the values in row, sum the values in column or some both columns and rows so sum of all cells.

These examples assume you are not having cells spaning through more then one row or column and that the total sum of your values is less then "long" size and each cell contains number that is "integer".

```
public void DisplayGridViewSums(GridView gv)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        long sum = SumValuesInRow(row);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of values in raw '{0}' is: {1}", row.RowIndex, sum);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<gv.Columns.Count;i++)
    {
        long sum = SumValuesInColumn(gv,i);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of values in column '{0}' with header '{1}' is: {2}",i, gv.Columns[i].HeaderText, sum);
    }
    long totalsum = SumColumnsAndRowsInGridView(gv);
    Console.WriteLine("Sum of all cells in each row is: {0}", totalsum);
}

public long SumColumnsAndRowsInGridView(GridView gv)
{
    long sum = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        sum += SumValuesInRow(row);
    }
    return sum;
}

public long SumValuesInRow(GridViewRow row)
{
    long sum = 0;
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        sum += int.Parse(cell.Text);
    }
    return sum;
}

public long SumValuesInColumn(GridView gv, int columnIndx)
{
    long sum = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        sum += int.Parse(row.Cells[columnIndx].Text);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

First method shows the sums on console. The other count the sums for particular GridView. Those counting methods could be written using Linq but for your convenience a left them as simple for and foreach loops.

Hope it solves your problem!